# Sending kill signal using a setuid process results in Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, permissions, setuid

I want to be able to send a SIGHUP signal to a Prometheus process from a CI tool that runs with a different user than Prometheus. Let's say CI uses `gitlab-runner` user and Prometheus uses `prometheus` user. I thought that I can achieve sending a SIGHUP signal to the Prometheus process by following steps:

1. Creating a simple shell script that executes `kill` command:

```
$ cat `which promhup`
kill -HUP $(pgrep prometheus)
```

2. Change the ownership of this script and set the `setuid` bit for this file:

```
chown prometheus promhup
chmod +x promhup
chmod u+s promhup
```

Then, I expected that if I simply run `promhup`, it can send the desired signal to the Prometheus process. However, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/promhup: line 1: kill: (602) - Operation not permitted
```

The permissions now look like this:

```
$ ls -l `which promhup`
-rwsr-xr-x 1 prometheus root 51 Jan 27 19:36 /usr/bin/promhup
```

What have I done wrong? How can I accomplish this without giving a `sudo` access to my CI user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first paragraph of @O.W.Grant's answer gave a great point in solving the problem:

> Linux ignores setuid bit on scripts/interpreted executables (the ones that start with #!) for the reasons of security.

It inspired me to write an equivalent program in C, which worked:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *fp;
  char pid[10];

  fp = popen("/usr/bin/pgrep prometheus", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
    exit(1);

  fgets(pid, sizeof(pid), fp);

  char* ptr = pid;
  while(ptr) {
    if(*ptr == '\n') {
      *ptr = '\0';
      break;
    }
    ptr++;
  }

  pclose(fp);

  char* args[] = {"/usr/bin/kill", "-HUP", pid, NULL};
  execvp(args[0], args);

  return 0;
}
```

The usage would be:

```bsh
gcc promhup.c -o promhup
chmod +x promhup
chown prometheus promhup
chmod u+s promhup
sudo mv promhup /usr/bin
```

Then running a simple `promhup` command would send a `SIGHUP` signal to the Prometheus process.

Comment: @user1686 Ouch, you're right. My thoughts were biased on using shell commands and I didn't even think about the system calls world.

Answer (score 1):

Linux ignores setuid bit on scripts/interpreted executables (the ones that start with #!) for the reasons of security.

As a kind of hacky solution you can try to compile a simple binary out of your script using https://github.com/neurobin/shc and setuid it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neurobin/ppa
sudo apt-get install shc

shc -f my_promhup_script -o promhup
sudo mv promhup /usr/bin/
```

Although I'd rather go for the sudo option - that's what it was designed for.

**Update:**

For the sudo option, you can add something like this to your sudoers:

```
gitlab-runner ALL = (ALL) ALL
gitlab-runner ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/promhup
```

this will make your sudo not ask password only for your script, while asking it for the others

source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt

Comment: Thanks! About `sudo`, I thought that using `sudo` approach would introduce additional security risks, since I need to give it passwordless `sudo` access because of the nature of its execution. That's why I think it can be risky in this case. I will try the `shc` approach and will be back here!

Comment: It seems that `shc` can't work either. I suppose that `$(pgrep prometheus)` is tricky here. The output that I get is `promhup: ���D|?r����A�V�C3��^Dk` with status code 1.

Comment: @Ali Tou you can make sudo not ask for password for specific binaries or scripts. Check this out: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt. Added it to the answer.

Comment: Hi. Just came here to firstly thank you for the time you spent for my question. The first paragraph you mentioned inspired me to write an equivalent program in C, which worked. I'm gonna add it as a separate answer for the record.